# delete and reset html table row ids for the rest of the table

Tags: jquery, html

how to reset the html table row id and name after deleting the row using jquery. For example html table has 5 rows and If I delete the 3rd row, then actual 4th and 5th row **textbox id** should become 3 and 4

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add").on("click",function() {
var data ='<tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" id="name2" value=""/></td><td><input type="text" id="phone2" value=""/></td><td><input type="text" id="email2" value=""/></td><td><button id="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>';
$("tbody").append(data);
});
</script>
<button id="add">Add Row</button>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" id="name1" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="phone1" value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="email1" value=""/></td>
<td><button id="delete">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

So first you must declare a global counter for that `window.globalCounter = 2;` where you'll store the rows counter. (what index will have the added row)

Then when you add you increment that `window.globalCounter++`.

And when you delete, you must fetch the currentRow, decrement the counter, and refactor the indexes.

```
  $("tbody").on("click", "#delete", function (ev) {

        // delete row
        var $currentTableRow = $(ev.currentTarget).parents('tr')[0];
        $currentTableRow.remove();
        window.globalCounter--;

        // refactor indexes
        $('table').find('tr').each(function (index) {
            var firstTDDomEl = $(this).find('td')[0];
            var $firstTDJQObject = $(firstTDDomEl);
            $firstTDJQObject.text(index + 1);
        });

    });
```

Here is a working code snippet.

```js
window.globalCounter = 2;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        var data = '<tr><td>' + window.globalCounter + '</td><td><input type="text" id="name2" value=""/></td><td><input type="text" id="phone2" value=""/></td><td><input type="text" id="email2" value=""/></td><td><button id="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>';
        $("tbody").append(data);
        window.globalCounter++;
    });

    $("tbody").on("click", "#delete", function (ev) {
        var $currentTableRow = $(ev.currentTarget).parents('tr')[0];
        $currentTableRow.remove();
        window.globalCounter--;
        
        $('table').find('tr').each(function (index) {
            var firstTDDomEl = $(this).find('td')[0];
            var $firstTDJQObject = $(firstTDDomEl);
            $firstTDJQObject.text(index + 1);
        });
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add Row</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="name1" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="phone1" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="email1" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="delete">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you have an alternative working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cn5p4oke/

Of course you must adjust the phone2, email2, name2 ids.

Please note that i used jQuery 2.1.0.

Comment: If this answer is suitable for you, please accept it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Otherwise, you can left a comment here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var row = $(document.getElementById(id));  //Or continue to use the invalid ID selector:  '#'+id
    var siblings = row.siblings();
    row.remove();
    siblings.each(function(index) {
         $(this).children('td').first().text(index + 1);
    });
</script>
```